# Pass an object to null if some values are empty

Tags: javascript

I have an object :

```
 contact:{
   email: ""
   firstName: ""
   id: 800
   lastName: ""
   phone: ""
   title: "MS"
   url: "/api/contacts/800"
  }
```

I would like to pass the whole object Contact to null, if the "`lastName`", "`firstName`", "`Phone`" and "`email`" fields are empty.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: u mean turning all other fields to null?

Comment: Please share what is you expected output and what did you try.

Comment: What do you mean "pass the whole object contact to null"?! Set `contact` to null?

Comment: Now we know a little bit of what you like to have. But this is not a "we code it for free" site, what have you tried to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you are expecting but you can try this :

```
let contact = {
  email: "",
  firstName: "",
  id: 800,
  lastName: "",
  phone: "",
  title: "MS",
  url: "/api/contacts/800"
};

if (
  contact.email === "" ||
  contact.firstName === "" ||
  contact.lastName === "" ||
  contact.phone === ""
) {
  contact = null;
}

console.log(contact);
```